# Why is my DropDownList not working?

Tags: c#, asp.net

I would like to display a DropdownList but  it isn't working yet.
This is my asp.net code:

```
<asp:Panel ID="pnlChannel" runat="server">
<asp:SqlDataSource ID="sdsChannel" runat="server"></asp:SqlDataSource>
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlChannel" runat="server"> 
    <asp:ListItem id="limDefault" runat="server"></asp:ListItem>
    </asp:DropDownList>
</asp:Panel>
```

And then this is my codebehind:

```
  public Panel GetDropDownList()
{
    // Create drop down list and data source
    Panel pnlChannel = new Panel();
    DropDownList ddlChannel = new DropDownList();
    ListItem limDefault = new ListItem();
    SqlDataSource sdsChannel = new SqlDataSource();

    // Configure data source
    sdsChannel.ConnectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["CR_SQL"].ConnectionString;
    sdsChannel.SelectCommand = "SELECT * FROM TABLE";
    sdsChannel.ID = "sdsChannel";

    // Configure drop down list
    ddlChannel.DataTextField = "Channel";
    ddlChannel.DataValueField = "Channel";
    ddlChannel.AppendDataBoundItems = true;
    ddlChannel.DataSourceID = "sdsChannel";



    // Configure default list item
    limDefault.Selected = true;
    limDefault.Text = "All";
    limDefault.Value = "-1";

    // Add controls to static panel in footer
    ddlChannel.Items.Add(limDefault);
    pnlChannel.Controls.Add(ddlChannel);
    pnlChannel.Controls.Add(sdsChannel);
    return pnlChannel;
}
```

Did I miss something?
So I think the ListItem isn't working, because there is a DropDownList but I can't see any list to drop down.

Comment: Why are you creating all controls again in code behind? You have already controls in the aspx page. Line  Panel pnlChannel = new Panel();  is creating the new panel. you are adding the other controls to panel bu creating new controls.

Comment: So I can just delete them?

Comment: When you call this function `public Panel GetDropDownList()`? And what technology did you use?

Comment: What do you mean with technology?

Comment: What do you mean by "not working"?

Answer (score 0):

You have not set `Text` property of `ListItem`. Also remove code from `.cs` file for creating controls because this will duplicate the controls.

```
<asp:DropDownList ID="ddlChannel" runat="server"> 
    <asp:ListItem id="limDefault" runat="server" Text="SomeText" Value="SomeValue"></asp:ListItem>
    </asp:DropDownList>
```

Comment: but if I do it like that I only get the "SomeText" Dropdown, but it should write the values from the database inside.